# jquery ui widget - how to call overriden event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, widget

i am building custom jquery ui widget and i've added custom event.
When i instantiate the widget i can override the original event handler.
How can i call the original event handler from the new one?

Example:

```
$.widget("myns.mywidget", {
    options: {
        myoption: null,
        myevent: function(event, ui){
            alert("original event handler");
        }
    },
    myMethod: function(){
        [...]
        this._trigger("myevent", {}, {});
    }
});
```

When i do:

```
$("#target").mywidget();
$("#target").mywidget("myMethod");
```

I see the message "original event handler".
Instead if i do:

```
 $("#target").mywidget({
     myevent: function(event, ui){
         alert("overriden event handler");
     }
 });
 $("#target").mywidget("myMethod");
```

I see the message "overriden event handler".
How can i execute also the original event handler from the overridden ?
Something like:

```
 $("#target").mywidget({
     myevent: function(event, ui){
         alert("overriden event handler");
         original.myevent();
     }
 });
 $("#target").mywidget("myMethod");
```

for see both messages "overriden event handler" and "original event handler" ?
thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
$("#target").mywidget({
    myevent: function(event, ui){
        alert("overriden event handler");
        $.myns.mywidget.prototype.options.myevent.call(this, event, ui);
    }
});
$("#target").mywidget("myMethod");
```

If someone has a better solution please let me know.
Thanks